# Attempting a Strategy design pattern in JS

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'm going through the *Head First Design Patterns* book and I want to check whether I'm understanding some aspects of the first chapter. Does the code below program correctly to interfaces, encapsulate changeable behavior, and employ composition in a reasonable manner?

```
// trying to enforce some design pattern habits

// create a duck, that prints a line to the page as text
class DuckAbilities {
    constructor() {
        this.flying = new FlyBehavior()
    }
    addToPage() {
        this.statement = document.createElement("p")
        this.statement.innerHTML=this.flying.fly()
        document.body.append(this.statement)
    }
}
//interface for behaviors
class FlyBehavior {
    fly() {
        null
    }
 }

class DoesFly{
    fly() {
        return "I'm flying"
    }
}
class DoesNotFly {
    fly() {
        return "not flying"
    }
}

class Mallard {
    constructor() {
        this.abilities = new DuckAbilities()
        this.abilities.flying = new DoesFly()
    }

}

class Rubber{
    constructor() {
        this.abilities = new DuckAbilities()
        this.abilities.flying = new DoesNotFly()
    }
}


window.onload = ()=> {
    let mallard = new Mallard()
    mallard.abilities.addToPage()
    let rubber = new Rubber()
    rubber.abilities.addToPage()
}
```

Comment: As Javascript, no, this is not "spiritually" nor technically an `Interface` implementation. Due to JS's nature proper interface-y code will not look like the examples in `Head First.`  Google  for JS specific examples - which will be different depending on the version of JS you use.

Comment: And [searching StackOverflow can be very helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3710275/463206) as well.

Comment: Javascript syntax does not map well to the classic OOP pattern class diagrams. I'd stick with the `Head First` book and forget JS for its sake - I like the `Head First` series a lot & have several of their titles, including `Design Patterns`.

Comment: Thank you for the additional insight! I'll try to implement code from this book in a language that has interfaces, and I think it will confuse me less because it will be of obvious use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some issues with your class, but I don't think that they are so specific to implementing a strategy pattern.

```
addToPage() {
    this.statement = document.createElement("p")
    this.statement.innerHTML=this.flying.fly()
    document.body.append(this.statement)
}
```

This assumes there is a global document variable, and that `statement` is part of the abilities object. If such a method is present, I would expect `document` to be a parameter of the method and `statement` to be a local variable. But even that doesn't seem right because you would be mixing representation (a paragraph `"p"`) and a data class.

```
//interface for behaviors
class FlyBehavior {
    fly() {
        null
    }
 }
```

Now that doesn't seem right. If you have JS ducktyping then you don't need this class. Furthermore, specifying `null` is just asking for null pointer exceptions at a later stage.

```
this.abilities = new DuckAbilities()
```

OK, so now we have `DuckAbilities` object but without a valid state, just `null`, which we then adjust in the next call. There seem to be two ways of resolving this issue:

1. having the fying behavior as parameter to the `DuckAbilities` constructor;
2. removing the `DuckAbilities` altogether and just assigning the various flybehaviors to a field.

---

So when we're using classes anyway, lets implement it using those.

I've created an "abstract" class Duck because we require inheritance there. I don't like to create an interface for the strategies because JavaScripts duck-typing should be sufficient.

```
'use strict'

class Duck { // this is the context
    constructor(flyAbility) {
        // ES2015 only, avoid instantiation of Duck directly
        // if (new.target === Abstract) {
        //  throw new TypeError("Cannot construct Abstract instances directly");
        // }

        this.flyAbility = flyAbility;
    }

    // this is the operation, returning the flyBehavior as a string
    showFlyBehavior() {
        return "This duck " + this.flyAbility.flyBehavior();
    }
}

// Strategy interface is missing due to JS ducktyping

// Strategy #1 
class DoesFly {
    // with algorithm #1
    flyBehavior() {
        return "flies";
    }
}

// Strategy #2
class DoesNotFly {
    // with algorithm #2
    flyBehavior() {
        return "doesn't fly";
    }
}

// Context #1
class Mallard extends Duck {
    constructor() {
        super(new DoesFly());
    }
}

// Context #2
class Rubber extends Duck {
    constructor() {
        super(new DoesNotFly());
    }
}

let duck = new Mallard();
console.log(duck.showFlyBehavior());

duck = new Rubber();
console.log(duck.showFlyBehavior());
```

Sorry about using NodeJS, but in principle only `console.log` is NodeJS specific ... I hope.

Comment: Direct answer, I'd still use a different language at least to *study* design patterns.

Comment: In Python `FlyBehavior` would be an [ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html), which is known simply as [abstract classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)#Abstract_and_concrete) elsewhere. If JavaScript supported this; do you think it would be a good use case here?

Comment: No, not really, because `FlyBehavior` doesn't have any generic behavior. Python is as much ducktyped as JavaScript, so it is just not necessary.  However, with Python you could at least make `Duck` an abstract base class (ABC) to avoid instantiation.

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot of sense to me. I would assume if this were TypeScript - since the duck typing kinda flys out the window, `FlyBehaviour` would become an interface. Thank you. :)